# Why can't I initialize a ViewState variable like other variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, variables, viewstate

I was testing some code using a ViewSate variable in asp.net c#.

I tried to initialize a ViewState variable and clearly I had an error from the compiler, please give me a thoretical explanation of the error.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int value = 0;
    ViewState["vsValue"]=value;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack==false)
        {
            Label1.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ViewState["vsValue2"]=value;
        value++;
        Label1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can only put definitions of variables at class scope. Any other code (like initializing array/dictionary elements as in your case) need to be inside methods or constructors.

Most likely equivalent of what you trying to do is adding initialization to `Page_Load` (as constructor may be too early in page's lifetime)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["vsValue"]=value;
    if (IsPostBack==false)
    {
        Label1.Text = value.ToString();
    }
}
```

For regular class such code would go to constructor:

```
class Foo
{
   Dictionary<string,string> map = new Dictionary<string,string>();

   public Foo()
   {
      map["One"] = "1";
   }
```

Comment: Yep moving the initialization of the statevariable in the load method gives me no error. But if the issue is initializing it, What if I don't initialize the ViewState variable and just declare it outside and above the load method, just typing: ViewState["vsValue"];  I still get an error.

Comment: @Luther `ViewState["vsValue3"]` is not "declaration" of `ViewState` but rather using element at `vsValue3`, `ViewState` is declared in one of base classes. (Also your personal definition of "declared" may not be the same, I'd recommend reading and aligning with language specification when asking question).

Comment: Just a minor comment on your code, settings `ViewState["vsValue"]` outside the `IsPostBack==false` block will cause all postbacks to overwrite the ViewState value - meaning you could never read it back on subsequent postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not initializing the ViewState variable but rather putting a value inside the dictionary that comprises the ViewState. These are different actions.

If you meant to assign the ViewState it would look lik

```
 ViewState = new Dictionary<>;
```

Which - apart from errors in types and the generic expression - probably wouldn't be allowed as the ViewState property setter is most likely private.

But you are using the indexer to set the value for the key/value-pair with key "vsValue". That is simply not valid c#.

If you were able to assign anything to ViewState you could use dictionary initialization like

```
  ViewState = new Dictionary <string, object>
        {{"vsValue", 1}, {"vsValue2", 2}};
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason you want to do this is because you want to declare that as a variable once and use it across your page's methods. you could achieve this by set a ViewState as a property on your page as below:

> ```
>     private string MyValue
>     {
>         get { return (string)(ViewState["vsValue"] ?? (object)null); }
>         set { ViewState["vsValue"] = value; }
>     }
>
> //as an example you may have two click event buttons as below
>
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     MyValue = "value1";
>     value++;
>     Label1.Text = value.ToString();
> }
>
> protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
>     Label2.Text = MyValue; //e.g. set the previous value first
>
>     MyValue = "value2"; //e.g. change this value now
>     
>     ...
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

if (IsPostBack==false)///First time the page loads initialise variable value
    {
         ViewState["vsValue"]=value;
    }
}`
```

Answer (score -1):

What you are calling a variable is not a variable.

`ViewState` is a special dictionary which is available to the page. When you refer to `ViewState` in a page, you are actually referring to `Page.ViewState`.

Individual entries in `ViewState` can be accessed using an *indexer*:

```
ViewState["MyInteger"] = 123;
int myInteger = (int) ViewState["MyInteger"];
```

This is not a variable, any more than "session variables" are variables:

```
Session["MyInteger"] = 123;
int myInteger = (int) Session["MyInteger"];
```

Just like anywhere else in .NET, an assignment statement can only be used inside of a method or property - it cannot be used as a declaration.